# How to make a React component look more readable and clean from my example?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have started working with React a month ago. Now I am building a step by step application. I have my code, but I have the feeling that I can clean it up even more.

Can someone check this code.. and give me advice which from I can learn and improve my React skills?

My Code works but wondering if this can be cleaner:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        fragrances: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    const URI = 'http://localhost:1337/';
    const post_type = 'fragrances';

        axios
        .get(`${URI + post_type}`)

        .then(response => {
            const fragrances = response.data;
            this.setState({ fragrances });
        })

        .catch(error => {
            console.log('An error occurred:', error);
        });
    }

    render() {
    const { fragrances } = this.state;
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row">
            {
                fragrances.map((fragrance, index) => {
                const url = 'http://localhost:1337';
                const image = fragrance.Image;
                const name = fragrance.Name;
                const category = fragrance.Category;
                const desc = fragrance.Description;
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div className="fragrance">
                                { image ? <img className="fragrance__image" src={url + image.url} alt={name} /> : <h4>Geen foto beschikbaar.</h4>}
                                { name ? <h2 className="fragrance__title">{name}</h2> : 'Geen titel aanwezig.'}
                                { category ? <span class="fragrance__category">{category}</span> : '    '}
                                { desc ? <p className="fragrance__description">{desc}</p> : 'Geen omschrijving aanwezig.'}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To follow coding standards, you can add "eslint" to your project which will force you to follow standard rules. You can integrate eslint provided by airbnb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `<Fragrance />` component would make it more clean plus using ES6 deconstruction. Also the `Fragment` is unnecessary around the list as it is being wrapped in a single `<div className="row">`:

```
....

render() {
  const { fragrances } = this.state;
  const url = 'http://localhost:1337';

  return (
      <div className="row">
        {fragrances.map((fragrance, index) => {
           const { Image: image, Name: name, Category: category, Description: desc } = fragrance;
            return (
              <Fragrance
                key={index}
                image={image}
                name={name}
                category={category}
                desc={desc}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

...
```

**Fragrance.js**

```
const Fragance = ({name, category, image, desc }) => (
  <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div className="fragrance">
      { image ? <img className="fragrance__image" src={url + image.url} alt={name} /> : <h4>Geen foto beschikbaar.</h4>}
      { name ? <h2 className="fragrance__title">{name}</h2> : 'Geen titel aanwezig.'}
      { category ? <span class="fragrance__category">{category}</span> : '    '}
      { desc ? <p className="fragrance__description">{desc}</p> : 'Geen omschrijving aanwezig.'}
     </div>
   </div>
)

export default Fragrance;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to preform the 'Reformat code'. As far as I know most Intellij IDE's have this, which can be preformed by pressing: CTRL + ALT + L.

This together with a (strict)  linter (ESLint) can result in a clear overall structure and thus increased readability.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code Observation:**

- Code inside **componentDidMount()** can be moved to some central place, like some separate component which exports these, all **axios** code resides there.
- Always try to break component in **smaller and manageable pieces**, which improves readability and also makes it more manageable.
- **Format the code** in such a way that all your code lies in the viewable area, we shouldn't scroll horizontally to see the running code.
- Your code inside `<div className="fragrance">` can be improved on readability, like below, try to always make it clean, this way it better to read.

  ```
  const { fragrances } = this.state;
  const image = <img className="fragrance__image" src={url + image.url} alt={name} />;
  const name = <h2 className="fragrance__title">{name}</h2>;
  const category = <span class="fragrance__category">{category}</span>;
  const desc = <p className="fragrance__description">{desc}</p>;

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
      <div className="row">
      {
          fragrances.map((fragrance, index) => {
          const url = 'http://localhost:1337';
          const image = fragrance.Image;
          const name = fragrance.Name;
          const category = fragrance.Category;
          const desc = fragrance.Description;
              return (
                  <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <div className="fragrance">
                          { image ? {image} : <h4>Geen foto beschikbaar.</h4>}
                          { name ? {name} : 'Geen titel aanwezig.'}
                          { category ? {category}  : '    '}
                          { desc ? {desc}  : 'Geen omschrijving aanwezig.'}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              )
          })
      }
      </div>
  </React.Fragment>
  )
  ```
- Please don't use **index** in map has **Key** , it will lead to unpredictable apps, please read this article [index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)
- Consider using HOC ( Higher Order Components ) [React HOC](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-react-higher-order-components-by-example-95e8c47c8006)
- Use CSS Modules to avoid CSS clashes [CSS Modules](https://blog.pusher.com/css-modules-react/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// conatnsts.js
export const URI = 'http://localhost:1337/';
export const URL = 'http://localhost:1337';
export const POST_TYPE = 'fragrances';


// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { URI, URL, POST_TYPE } from './constants.js';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        fragrances: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .get(`${URI + post_type}`)
          .then(response => {
            const fragrances = response.data;
            this.setState({ fragrances });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('An error occurred:', error);
        });
    }

    render() {
      const { fragrances } = this.state;
      return (
        <>
          <div className="row">
            {
                fragrances.map(({ Image: image, Name: name, Category: category, Description: desc}, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div className="fragrance">
                      {image ? <img className="fragrance__image" src={URL + image.url} alt={name} /> : <h4>Geen foto beschikbaar.</h4>}
                      {name ? <h2 className="fragrance__title">{name}</h2> : 'Geen titel aanwezig.'}
                      {category ? <span class="fragrance__category">{category}</span> : '    '}
                      {desc ? <p className="fragrance__description">{desc}</p> : 'Geen omschrijving aanwezig.'}
                    </div>
                  </div>)
                )
              }
           </div>
        </>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

I added slight changes, but to keep your code clean and more readable in React write component only for the purpose that it should serve. Your component shouldn't think about how to render image or category or description. Instead you should have a component smth like `FragranceListItem`. This component(App component) is the `FragranceList`. So your `FragranceList` component renders `FragranceListItem`s. In a `FragranceListItem` you can have `FragranceImage`, `FragranceName`, `FragranceCategory`, `FragranceDescription` components, which will get needed info by the `props` and they will decide how to show their data if condition is true or not. Think about components like functions. Function should be simple, it should do only one thing, the same React component.

And what about fetching data and placing it in a state. If this is a small applications, that this works. But if it will get bigger, the need of libraries such as `redux`, `react-redux`, `redux-thunks`, `redux-sagas` will appear. These libraries have their approaches how to keep your application state, how to make serverside calls from separate modules and hold side-effects far from your components.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move API logic to separate module.
2. Move fragrance description to separate component.
3. Consider using HOC for getting data and functional component to render it.
4. Use prettier to format your code. https://prettier.io
5. If it’s a real application, consider using state management lib like Redux.